# Shifting UITableView down (UITableViewController)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am just wondering whether or not it is possible to shift a `UITableView` down the page by, say, maybe 50 pixels. I know this would usually work if I had used a `UIViewController` then added a table view on top, but would I be able to do this and still keep it as `UITableViewController`?

Comment: question makes no sense a bit more explanation ? what u mean by "keep it as UITableViewController"

Comment: What I mean is, If i have a UIViewController and add a TableView, I can position the table view. However, when using a UITableViewController, I dont know how I would go about shifting the table down as when you select it in the .xib file, the x and y co-ordinates are not editable.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't switch to UIViewController with a UITableView subview? It gives you a lot more flexibility.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had the same problem and the answer above didn't work. This did:

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50,0,0,0)];
```

Comment: Thank you!! Worked perfectly!!

Comment: But one can still scroll on the inseted area. How do I make it unscrollable?

Comment: For Swift, it looks like this: self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: Valid answer works for me, in Swift4.1, Xcode 9.3, it changes to 

`self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 84, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)`

Answer (score 8):

My solution is to override tableViewcontroller's method viewWillLayoutSubviews

```
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame),300);
}
```

Works great and always for me with changing orientations and in all situations

Comment: Best solution to my opinion

Comment: For Xamarin iOS, this is what works.  The accepted answer doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

A `UITableView` is actually a `UIScrollView`. This means that you can scroll the `UITableView` to the point you want. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404745/change-the-speed-of-setcontentoffsetanimated) is a previous link which shows you how to do this, including sample code and discussion.

***Edit:*** In order to shift the **WHOLE** tableview down, just use:

```
float yOffset = 50.0f; // Change this how much you want!
tableview.view.frame =  CGRectMake(tableview.view.frame.origin.x, tableview.view.frame.origin.y + yOffset, tableview.view.frame.size.width, tableview.view.frame.size.height);
```

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Yeah understand that, I'm not wondering how to scroll it down, im wondering how i can shift the whole table down the view, to allow for some space for some text at the top. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You add it where you want it to be called. So if you want to call it in the beginning, before the user does anything, put it in the `viewDidLoad:` method. If you want it to be tied with a button, put it in the buttons `IBAction`, etc.

Comment: If he puts it on the viewDidLoad: the entire view is likely to have a very unpleasant "jump" effect...

Comment: This doesnt work for me, however it seems like a decent solution and its the best answer so far, thanks! Ive decided im just gonna work around the problem, and keep it how it is. Thanks alot though

Answer (score 2):

Since a Table View is backed by a UIScrollView you can move in around using the content Offset.

```
  self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake( x,  y);
```

You might want to wrap in a UIView animation

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to add a UI element at the top of the table, why not just set it to the `tableHeaderView` instead?

```
UILabel *someLabel;

// configure label

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = someLabel;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a view behind (or on top of) the tableview, then you'll have to subclass `UIViewController` instead and add a `UITableView` afterwards.
Another solution could be to set the table's header view ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView)) but in this case, keep in mind that this view will scroll together with the table.
More information about the limitations of `UITableViewController` in this article: "[Clean table view code](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/table-views.html)".

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 2.2:**

To shift the tableView inside a UITableViewController down:

```
let edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0)
self.tableView.contentInset = edgeInsets
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewController is actually a UIViewController, only plus is it gives you some methods to override and useful for table actions. so you can do whatever you want

check this, once you get the idea of what UITableViewController actully is you will do whatever you want

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/03/recreating-uitableviewcontroller-to.html