# How change speed of "scrollView.setContentOffset"

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

How can i change scrollview speed of "setContentOffset"?

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 120.5, y: 0), animated: true)
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4404745/1050261

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)` inside an animation block

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: yOffset), animated: false)
        })
```